# Why can some aircraft not fly near the north pole?

Tags: airline-operations, airbus-a320, pilot-certification, airbus, airlines

The Adiru on the Airbus 320 has an limit like 84°N latitude. What happens if the plane is flown above that latitude?

Comment: Hello, where do you take this limit from? Could you be misled by the limits related to magnetic heading computation area?

Comment: Related: [Can you fly with INS/ IRS at higher lattitudes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90315/can-you-fly-with-ins-irs-at-higher-lattitudes)

Comment: I am retired and no longer have access to the aircraft manuals, but I believe the B777 is not certified to fly over the True North Pole.

Answer (score 4):

You don't get a valid heading and track angle. Each ADIRU model has different characteristics and limitation. This is an example from an FCOM that I have:

[image: FCOM page]

---

Special flights can fly in these conditions, but they don't use magnetic headings (see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/is-the-heading-used-near-the-pole)).